# Android: Improving performance of a ListView containing Horizontal ScrollView in each row

Tags: performance, view, android-listview, reusability, horizontalscrollview

I have a listview that contains a horizontal scrollView inside each row. 
Now when getView() is called for each position in the listView, I am creating and adding views (relative layouts) to the horizontal scrollView. This getView() is pretty cramped.

I am trying to improve the performance of my listview.
I do not store each of the views inside my horizontal scrollView for each position in list view as that would amount to storing all the views that go into the whole listView. This i wouldn't be taking advantage of view re-use feature.

But then how do i improve the performance as I am having to create the views inside the horizontal scrollView every time get view is called and that itself is quite heavy.

If i store these internal views (relative layouts) in a map (position, list of views) and then in get view just call that position get all the internal views and feed to my horizontal scroll view?

I am confused about this. could someone please help me in improving the performance here.

Thanks.
Sunny

Answer (score 0):

The main concept of `Listview` is to reuse the child components.

Basically, what you are doing could be wrong. `HorizontalScrollview` consumes a lot more memory than `ListView`, and I'm assuming that the `getView()` method is doing a lot of work.

My Suggestion:

`Listview` should be replaced with `ScrollView` and `HorizontalScrollView` should be replaced with `ViewPager` or `HorizontalListView`.

Note: If you want a perfect answer post a screenshot